# FIRE project Compile error "error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const __gnu_cxx::hash<char *>'"

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

When I try to compile the FIRE image processing project I get an error on MacOS. I've opened an issue here https://github.com/deselaers/fire-cbir/issues/3 but the maintainer is not working on the project anymore. I was going to use this for a school project but it won't compile. The main issue seems to be the following error.

```
In file included from Retriever/fire.cpp:42:
In file included from Retriever/server.hpp:23:
In file included from Retriever/distancemaker.hpp:28:
In file included from DistanceFunctions/dist_jsd.hpp:24:
Features/sparsehistogramfeature.hpp:60:12: error: no matching function for call to object of type
      'const __gnu_cxx::hash<char *>'
    return h(p.c_str());
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ext/__hash:38:12: note:
      candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('const std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
      std::__1::allocator<char> >::value_type *' (aka 'const char *')) would lose const qualifier
    size_t operator()(char *__c) const _NOEXCEPT
           ^
```

The maintainer suggests that it could be done with some compiler tuning. I'm not sure how to resolve the issue mostly because I'm not a C++ expert and I'm not sure what the issue is in the first place. Can someone help me debug this? Thanks!

Comment: Is sparcehistogramfeature.hpp one of YOUR files or one of the library's files?

Comment: `h` should take its argument as `const char *`.  Is this something you can change?

Comment: Sorry, it's one of the libraries files. I'm just trying to compile the binary of the library with a `make` right now.

Comment: It's not something I can change right now but the owner said the binary compiled on mac at some point. Is there an old version of c++ where this would work or something?